# Python Dictionary Sorting Using Sorted

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

This is a newbie question for which I could not find a precise answer for.  I would like to sort a dictionary in descending order according to the values.  i.e....

```
dict = {'ann': 9, 'tom': 21, 'eddie': 12, 'fred': 5}
```

I know that this works...

```
>>> sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
[('tom', 21), ('eddie', 12), ('ann', 9), ('fred', 5)]
```

But I am trying to understand how this part works...

```
x: x[1]
```

How is this matching the value attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict.items()` returns a list of `(key, value)` pairs, `x[1]` is simply the `value` part of that pair:

```
>>> d = {'ann': 9, 'tom': 21, 'eddie': 12, 'fred': 5}
>>> d.items()
[('ann', 9), ('fred', 5), ('eddie', 12), ('tom', 21)]
>>> d.items()[0]
('ann', 9)
>>> d.items()[0][1]
9
>>> (lambda x: x[1])(d.items()[0])
9
```

`sorted()` passes each element in the input sequence (so `('ann', 9)`, etc.) into the `key` function. `x` is then `('ann', 9)` and `x[1]` is `9`.

Answer (score 0):

**Let me explain whats going on:**

**Your dictionary:**

d = {'ann': 9, 'tom': 21, 'eddie': 12, 'fred': 5}

**Here is what sorted usage help says:**

```
sorted(...)
    sorted(iterable, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=False) --> new sorted list
```

**Lets break down :**

From your snipet:  **sorted(dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)**

iterable : d.items()

```
which is list of tuples, 

>>> d.items()
[('ann', 9), ('fred', 5), ('eddie', 12), ('tom', 21)]
>>>
```

key = lambda x: x[1]

NB: key parameter to specify a function to be called on each list element prior to making comparisons.

Lets apply to your case:

```
>>> key = lambda x: x[1]
>>> map(key, d.items())
[9, 5, 12, 21]
>>>
```

Which gave the values of the dictionary.

reverse=True showing below, hope you can understand easily from the example.

```
>>> l = [3,2,4,1]
>>> sorted(l)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> sorted(l, reverse=True)
[4, 3, 2, 1]
>>>
```

conclusion:

**You are reversing a dictionary based on value `d[1]` i.e value and reversed it.**
Final result is list of tuples i.e tuple[0] = key, tuple[1] = value.